# Creating Text files using Batch (Or anything) in an order / pattern

Tags: batch, text-editors, text-editing, text-formatting

I need to create a file to finish a mod i am working on, except it would take way too long to do it manually.

Cutting to the chase i need to create a file that looks like the following

```
1|5.000
2|4.950
3|4.900
4|4.850
```

And that *pattern* to be repeated X times or until the second number is 0.5 for example, the number before the " | " is not important, it's only for organization and / or naming, I can probably add it in post, I did this on a smaller scale manually of ~30 numbers and it was tedious enough, but i got to a point where i actually need this on a far larger scale.

I've yet to find a way to automate that kind of a process with "online text tools" and have been trying to figure out how to do patterns like that for a while, though it's a bit difficult to Google it *(Or at least for me, I'm not a native English speaker)*

What would be the best way to approach this?

***Thanks in advance guys!***

Comment: Use a `bash`/`awk`/`perl` script, or any language you are comfortable with. Otherwise use Excel and export to text file.

Comment: Ah, How did i not think of excel!! In fact even Google Sheets worked, just had to export as tab separated values format and open with Notepad++ and worked perfectly, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution in `perl`:

```
perl -e 'for ($i=1;$i<=90;$i++){printf("%s|%.3f\n", $i,5-.05*$i);}'>out.txt
```

You could use any programming language you might be comfortable with. In case there are none, you can accomplish the same with a spreadsheet (Excel, Gnumeric, Libreoffice Calc, Google Sheets...) and then export as a text file.

Answer (score 2):

Install **CudaText** editor. Free, cross-platform.

Call menu item "Plugins / Make plugin". Enter defaults, menuitem name "My".
New py file is created. Enter such body:

```
from cudatext import *
from decimal import Decimal

class Command:
    def run(self):

        v0 = Decimal('5.000')
        vend = Decimal('4.500')
        i = 0
        res = []
        while v0>vend:
            v0 -= Decimal('0.050')
            i += 1
            res += [str(i)+'|'+str(v0)]

        file_open('')
        ed.set_text_all('\n'.join(res))
```

- Restart CudaText
- Call menu item "Plugins / My"
- Output is created in a new file tab.